# Start Apache httpd on boot

Tags: launchd, apache

Since upgrading to Yosemite, Apache `httpd` is no longer started at boot time.

I've tried: `sudo launchctl load org.apache.httpd.plist` but I'm getting a `service is disabled` error.

I've modified the plist file and set `Disabled` key to `NO` but I still get the error. What am I missing here?

Comment: sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist  does that work for you

Comment: @Buscar웃 That did it! What does the -w switch do? Post an answer and I can mark it answered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem [here](http://clickontyler.com/support/a/38/how-start-apache-automatically/).

Using Terminal "How do I make Apache start automatically":

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

You were close to the solution just needed the -w override.

the `-w`      [Overrides the Disabled key and sets it to false](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html).

Comment: To elaborate on your answer, from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html -w Overrides the Disabled key and sets it to false.