# How to change the User/group setting for Apache installed with homebrew?

Tags: security, homebrew, apache

I am running an Apache server daemon on my local Mac with Mojave installed. Apache was installed with homebrew. I want to tighten up security on the server as I occasionally make some sites publicly available for a limited time.

One thing I need to fix is that the apache daemon is running under my user name on the mac despite having both `User` and `Group` setting in `httpd.conf` set to `_www`.

I searched the config directory in `/usr/local/etc/httpd` but didn't see any config setting that has set the daemon as my user. How do I get the `_www` setting to take? Where might it be getting overridden?

Comment: It's not something you're going to find in `httpd.conf`.  Apache runs as the user who starts it.  If *you* started it, it will be under you.  If you ran it with `sudo`, it will be running under root.  See the documentation:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/invoking.html

Comment: Also, have a look at this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344268/how-to-start-homebrew-apache-on-boot/344455#344455   and this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153774/start-apache-httpd-on-boot